# How to retrieve text from a website with Swift

Tags: html, json, swift, parsing

New to coding so spare me if this is rather simple. I'm trying to download text from a web page in swift, like from a news article, Wikipedia or something. I can get the HTML or JSON, but I cannot extract the text as a string. Thanks!

Comment: Use a HTML parser like [`TFHpple`](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) (written in Objective-C, but works great from Swift, too) or [`NDHpple`](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple) (written in Swift, but not as good as `TFHpple`, IMHO).

Comment: If you search for "[swift] HTML parse", you'll probably find links. [How to Parse HTML on iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) is dated and written in Objective-C, but it should walk you through all of the concepts necessary to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

try [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

Example:

```
do{
   let html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
            + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>"
   let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
   return try doc.text()
}catch Exception.Error(let type, let message)
{
    print("")
}catch{
    print("")
}
```